# is there any query to find record from mongodb that will ignore white spaces from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, meteor

For Example my collection company contains one document like

{
   name : "XYZ PVT LTD"
}

then i can find this document like

db.company.findOne({name :{regEx : "XYZPVTLTD"}});

Comment: `db.company.findOne({name :{$regex : /XYZ\s*PVT\s*LTD/}});`

Answer (score -1):

Create your regex as following

```js
let str = 'XYZPVTLTD';
let regex = new RegExp([...str].join('\\s*'));
console.log(regex.test('XYZ PVT LTD'))
```

```
db.company.findOne({name :{$regex : regex}});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass your search string without space, you must follow the below:

```
db.arraytest.findOne(
{name:{
    $regex : /XYZ\s*PVT\s*LTD/
    }})
```